# Zend Framework: Checking if route exists from code

Tags: zend-framework, routes

in zend framework, is there anyway i can check if a route exists from code?

**example**

say the following routes/urls are valid (point to controller/action)

```
/users
/users/1 // /users?id=1
/users/page/1  /users?page=1
/users/tagged/tagname/page/1 /users?tagged=1&page=1
```

if the user tries to goto `/users/nonexistantpage` it should fail. soemthing to check if the user request the url, will it fail, but on the code level.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're looking for the [match()](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.0/Zend_Controller/Router/Zend_Controller_Router_Route.html#match) method for the Zend router. See if that helps.

Comment: That method is from `Zend_Controller_Router_Route` when I do `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()` I get `Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite` how can I get a route, do I need to loop though all routes?

Comment: Anyway I tried doing http://pastie.org/1422932 but I found that a URI like `/projects/adashds` is valid matching the route http://pastie.org/1422935. obviously `adashdsAction` does not exists

Answer (score 1):

If you use rewrite router (`Zend_Controller_Router_Rewrite`), it has a method `hasRoute($route_name)`

Then if you want to check if route exists anywhere in your application you can check it like that:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->hasRoute("my_route");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda old question, but I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
foreach(Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->getRoutes() as $route)
{
    $route->match($uri);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those using Zend Framework 2, this is very simple.

Let say we want to check if an URI matches against registered router and redirect the user if this is different from the current url.

```
$goto = 'http://www.mysite.tld/admin';

$request  = $this->getRequest();
$request->setUri($goto);

if ($routeToBeMatched = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Router')->match($request)) {
    $currentRouteMatchName = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getMatchedRouteName();
    if ($routeToBeMatched->getMatchedRouteName() != $currentRouteMatchName) {
        return $this->redirect()->toRoute($goto);
    }
}
```